# Cant access value of JSON object

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, flask

Im doing a little project with flask. Right now, im trying to add options to a select from a JSON object.Despite being able to insert options, i cant access their value

This my flask code:

```
for dealership in session.query(Dealership).filter_by(ownerID = userId).all():
    dealership_list.append({'Name' : dealership.name})

return jsonify(names = dealership_list)
```

Ajax code:

```
success:function(result){
      $.each(result.names, function(Name, value) {
          $('#dealerships').append($("<option/>", {
              value: Name,
              text: value
          }));
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each item in `result.names` is a dealership (as defined by your view function).

each dealership is a dict consisting of `{"Name":the_name_of_this_dealership}`

so `$.each(result.names,function(data){console.log(data)}` should print each object which is `{"Name":some_dealership_name}`

so just change it to

```
success:function(result){
  $.each(result.names, function(dealership) {
      $('#dealerships').append($("<option/>", {
          value: dealership.Name,
          text: dealership.Name
      }));
  });
},
```

## - or -

better yet just change your python code to just return a list of names since thats the only data you are using

```
dealerships = session.query(Dealership).filter_by(ownerID = userId).all()
names = [dealership.name for dealership in dealerships]
return jsonify(names = names)
```

and just change your js to

```
success:function(result){
  $.each(result.names, function(index,a_dealer_name) {
      $('#dealerships').append($("<option/>", {
          value: a_dealer_name,
          text: a_dealer_name
      }));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@JoranBeasley Awesome!I used the second solution, but added/change the following:

```
$.each(result.names, function(key,name) {
    $('#dealerships').append($("<option/>", {
        value: name,
        text: name
    }));
});
```

This because your solution was printing the index instead of value.Thanks for the help!

Comment: fixed :) thanks for the heads up ... I dont do much js